# Как найти в массиве индекс первого значения Java

Tags: java, массивы, строки, char

Есть текст, преобразованный в String, затем преобразованный в массив char

```
String a = "/add (kesha) {100}";
char[] array = a.toCharArray();
```

**Как найти индекс элемента "("?**

Comment: В классе `String` есть метод [`String::indexOf(int c)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#indexOf(int)) для нахождения индекса первого вхождения элемента.  Если нужно сделать самописный поиск в массиве, используйте старый добрый цикл `for`

Comment: Переформулируйте ваш вопрос, расскажите подробнее, какую проблему вы решаете? Отредактируйте вопрос, нажав кнопку [править](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1437263/edit). Я сомневаюсь, что для решения вашей задачи нужен `char[]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чтобы достать Кешу, воспользутесь методами [`indexOf()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#indexOf(int)) и [`substring()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#substring(int,int)):

```
String a = "/add (kesha) {100}";
int start = a.indexOf('(');
int end = a.indexOf(')');
if (start != -1 && end != -1 && start < end) {
    String name = a.substring(start + 1, end);
    System.out.println(name);
}
```

Вывод:

```
kesha
```

Comment: Это намного лаконичнее, чем та жуть что я написал, спасибо)